# BibTex: I was expecting a ',' or a '}' in overleaf but everything seems fine

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am having this issue in overleaf. I have tried compiling other files, checking and re-checking if I am missing a ',' or '}', but that is not the case. I have even completely removed the entry and entered it again. Strangely, the same errors occur even if the bib entry is completely removed as if it can still read the entry but it is not typed in.

The issue is with three references in the bibliography file below.

```
%BOOKS
@book{Versteeg:2009,
    title        = {\emph{An Introduction to Computational Fluid Dynamics}},
    author       = {Versteeg, H. and Malalasekra, W.},
    year         = {2009},
    publisher    = {Pearson},
    isbn         = {9788131720486},
    edition      = {2nd Edition}
}

@BOOK{Moukalled:2016,
    title = {\emph{The Finite Volume Method in Computational Fluid Dynamics}},
    publisher = {Springer},
    author = {Moukalled, F. and Mangani, L. and Darwish, M},
    year = {2016},
    series = {Fluid Mechanics and Its Applications},
    isbn = {9783319168739}
}

@BOOK{Wilcox:1993,
    title = {\emph{Turbulence Modeling for CFD}},
    publisher = {DCW Industries Inc.},
    author = {Wilcox, C,D.},
    year = {1993},
    series = {},
    isbn = {0963605100}
}

@BOOK{Anderson:1995,
    title = {\emph{Computational Fluid Dynamics: The Basics with Applications}},
    publisher = {McGraw-Hill Education - Europe},
    author = {John Anderson},
    year = {1995},
    series = {},
    isbn = {9780071132107}
}

@BOOK{Gersten:2017,
    title = {\emph{Boundary-Layer Theory}}, 
    publisher = {Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg},
    author = {Klaus Gersten, Hermann Schlichting(Deceased)},
    year = {2017},
    series = {},
    isbn = {9783662529195}
}

@BOOK{Wiggert:2008,
    title = {\emph{Schaum`s outline of Fluid Mechanics}}, 
    publisher = {McGraw-Hill Education},
    author = {Merle C. Potter and David C. Wiggert},
    year = {2008},
    series = {Schaum`s outlines},
    isbn = {9780071487818}
}

@BOOK{Eckert:2007,
title = {\emph{The Dawn of Fluid Dynamics}},
publisher = {Wiley \& sons},
author = {Eckert, M.},
year = {2007},
isbn = {9783527610747}
}

@incollection{Holton:2004,
title = {Chapter 5 The planetary boundary layer},
editor = {James R. Holton},
series = {International Geophysics},
publisher = {Academic Press},
volume = {88},
pages = {115-138},
year = {2004},
booktitle = {An Introduction to Dynamic Meteorology},
issn = {0074-6142},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/S0074-6142(04)80039-1},
}

@BOOK{Lanchester:1907,
title = {Aerodynamics, constituting  the first volume of a complete work on aerial flight},
author = {Frederick W. Lanchester},
year = {1907},
publisher = {London, A. Constable \& Co., Ltd.}
}

%ARTICLES
@ARTICLE{Viola:2020,
    author = {~Otomo, S and Henne, S. and Mulleners, K and Ramesh, K and Viola, I,M.},
    title = {\emph{Unsteady lift on a high-amplitude pitching aerofoil}},
    journal = {Experiments in Fluids},
    year = {2021},
    volume = {62(6)},
    pages = {},
    number = {},
    month = {},
    publisher = {Springer}
}

@ARTICLE{Brunton:2012,
    author = {Brunton, S,L. and Rowley, C,W.},
    title = {\emph{Empirical State-Space Representations for Theodorsen's Lift Model}},
    journal = {Journal of Fluids and Structures},
    year = {2012},
    volume = {},
    pages = {},
    number = {},
    month = {},
    publisher = {Springer}
}

@ARTICLE{Theodorsen:1933,
    author = {Theodorsen, T. and Silverstein, A.},
    title = {\emph{Experimental verification of the theory of wind-tunnel boundary interface}},
    journal = {},
    year = {1933},
    volume = {},
    pages = {},
    number = {},
    month = {},
    publisher = {National Advisory Committee for Aeronautics}
}

@ARTICLE{Theodorsen:1935,
    author = {Theodorsen, T.},
    title = {\emph{General theory of aerodynamic instability and the mechanism of flutter}},
    journal = {},
    year = {1935},
    volume = {},
    pages = {},
    number = {},
    month = {},
    publisher = {National Advisory Committee for Aeronautics}
}

@article{Wang:2013,
author = {Wang,Shizhao  and Zhang,Xing  and He,Guowei  and Liu,Tianshu },
title = {A lift formula applied to low-Reynolds-number unsteady flows},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {25},
number = {9},
pages = {093605},
year = {2013},
doi = {10.1063/1.4821520},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4821520}
}


@article{Narayan:2015,
author = {Narayanan,S.  and Chaitanya,P.  and Haeri,S.  and Joseph,P.  and Kim,J. W.  and Polacsek,C. },
title = {Airfoil noise reductions through leading edge serrations},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {27},
number = {2},
pages = {025109},
year = {2015},
doi = {10.1063/1.4907798},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4907798}
}

@article{Chae:2013,
author = {Chae,Eun Jung  and Akcabay,Deniz Tolga  and Young,Yin Lu },
title = {Dynamic response and stability of a flapping foil in a dense and viscous fluid},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {25},
number = {10},
pages = {104106},
year = {2013},
doi = {10.1063/1.4825136},
URL = { https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4825136}
}

@article{Durbin:1994,
author = {Durbin,P. A.  and Mansour,N. N.  and Yang,Z. },
title = {Eddy viscosity transport model for turbulent flow},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {6},
number = {2},
pages = {1007-1015},
year = {1994},
doi = {10.1063/1.868334},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1063/1.868334}
}

@article{Zhang:2004,
author = {Zhang,Qiang  and Lee,Sang Woo  and Ligrani,Phillip M. },
title = {Effects of surface roughness and freestream turbulence on the wake turbulence structure of a symmetric airfoil},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {16},
number = {6},
pages = {2044-2053},
year = {2004},
doi = {10.1063/1.1736676},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1736676}
}

@article{Fadhila:2017,
author = {Fadhila,H.  and Medina,H.  and Beechook,A.  and Aleksandrova,S.  and Benjamin,S. },
title = {Evaluation of transition-sensitive eddy-viscosity turbulence models for separated flow in OpenFOAM},
journal = {AIP Conference Proceedings},
volume = {1863},
number = {1},
pages = {030034},
year = {2017},
doi = {10.1063/1.4992187},
URL = {https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4992187}
}

@article{Adrian:2007,
author = {Adrian,Ronald J. },
title = {Hairpin vortex organization in wall turbulence},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {19},
number = {4},
pages = {041301},
year = {2007},
doi = {10.1063/1.2717527},
URL = { https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2717527},
}

@article{Merrett:2012,
author = {Merrett,Craig G.  and Hilton,Harry H. },
title = {Highly flexible flight vehicle aeroelastic and aero-viscoelastic flutter issues},
journal = {AIP Conference Proceedings},
volume = {1493},
number = {1},
pages = {467-479},
year = {2012},
doi = {10.1063/1.4765530},
URL = {https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4765530}
}

@article{Linyang:2019,
author = {Zhu,Linyang  and Zhang,Weiwei  and Kou,Jiaqing  and Liu,Yilang },
title = {Machine learning methods for turbulence modeling in subsonic flows around airfoils},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {31},
number = {1},
pages = {015105},
year = {2019},
doi = {10.1063/1.5061693},
URL = { https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5061693}
}

@article{Brzobohaty:2015,
author = {Brzobohatý,Tomáš  and Říha,Lubomír  and Karásek,Tomáš  and Kozubek,Tomáš },
title = {Performance evaluation of OpenFOAM on many-core architectures},
journal = {AIP Conference Proceedings},
volume = {1648},
number = {1},
pages = {830004},
year = {2015},
doi = {10.1063/1.4913030},
URL = {https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4913030}
}

@article{Eyink:2015,
author = {Eyink,Gregory L. },
title = {Turbulent flow in pipes and channels as cross-stream “inverse cascades” of vorticity},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {20},
number = {12},
pages = {125101},
year = {2008},
doi = {10.1063/1.3013635},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3013635}
}

@article{Wang:2014,
author = {Wang,S.  and Zhou,Y.  and Alam,Md. Mahbub  and Yang,H. },
title = {Turbulent intensity and Reynolds number effects on an airfoil at low Reynolds numbers},
journal = {Physics of Fluids},
volume = {26},
number = {11},
pages = {115107},
year = {2014},
doi = {10.1063/1.4901969},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4901969}
}

@article{Priyadarshini:2015,
author = {Priyadarshini, J,S.  and Abhinav, AV,S. and Chandra, B.S. and Swathi, R,S.},
title = {Use of Aerodynamic Lift in increasing fuel efficiency of heavy vehicles},
journal = {Journal  of Mechanical and Civil Engineering},
volume = {12},
number = {4},
pages = {39-42},
year = {2015},
doi = {10.9790/1684-12413942},
URL = {https://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jmce/papers/vol12-issue4/Version-1/F012413942.pdf}
}

@article{Brunton:2019,
author = {Brunton, Steven L. and Noack, Bernd R. and Koumoutsakos, Petros},
title = {Machine Learning for Fluid Mechanics},
journal = {Annual Review of Fluid Mechanics},
volume = {52},
number = {1},
pages = {477-508},
year = {2020},
doi = {10.1146/annurev-fluid-010719-060214},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-fluid-010719-060214}
}

@article{Vogt:2010,
    author = {Vogt, J,W. and Barber, T,J},
    title = {Ground effect phenomena about lift and downforce generating cambered aerofoils},
    journal = {International Journal of Numerical Methods for Heat \& Fluid Flow},
    volume = {22},
    number = {2},
    pages = {153-174},
    year = {2012},
    doi = {10.1108/09615531211199809}
}

@article{Xu:2020,
    author = {Xu, Yuncheng. and Liu, Xiaofeng},
    title = {An immersed boundary method with y + ‐adaptive wall function for smooth wall shear},
    journal = {International Journal for Numerical Methods in Fluids},
    volume = {},
    number = {},
    pages = {},
    year = {2020},
    doi = {10.1002/fld.4960},
    URL = {https://doi.org/10.1002/fld.4960}
}

@article{Schmitt:2007,
author = {Schmitt G, Fran\c{c}ois.},
title = {About Boussinesq’s turbulent viscosity hypothesis: historical remarks and a direct evaluation of its validity}, 
journal = {Comptes Rendus Mécanique},
volume = {335},
number = {9-10},
pages = {617-627},
year = {2007},
doi = {10.1016/j.crme.2007.08.004}
}

@article{Rodionov:2010,
title = {On the use of Boussinesq approximation in turbulent supersonic jet modeling},
journal = {International Journal of Heat and Mass Transfer},
volume = {53},
number = {5},
pages = {889-901},
year = {2010},
issn = {0017-9310},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijheatmasstransfer.2009.11.035},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0017931009006358},
author = {Alexander V. Rodionov}
}

@article{Stokes:1845,
title = {On the theories of the internal friction of fluids in motion, and of the equilibrium and motion of elastic solids},
author = {Stokes G, G.},
journal = {Transactions of the Cambridge Philosophical Society},
volume = {8},
pages = {287-305},
year = {1845}
}

@article{Stokes:1856,
title = {On the effect of the internal friction of fluids on the motion of pendulums},
author = {Stokes G, G.},
journal = {Transactions of the Cambridge Philosophical Society},
volume = {9},
pages = {1-100},
year = {1856}
}

@article{Navier:1827,
    title        = {M´emoire sur les lois du mouvement des fluides},
    author       = {Navier, CLMH.},
    year         = 1827,
    journal      = {M´em. de l’Acad. d. Sci.},
    volume       = 6,
    pages        = {389--416}
}

@incollection{KUNDU:2016,
title = {Chapter 10 - Boundary Layers and Related Topics},
editor = {Pijush K. Kundu and Ira M. Cohen and David R. Dowling},
booktitle = {Fluid Mechanics (Sixth Edition)},
publisher = {Academic Press},
edition = {Sixth Edition},
address = {Boston},
pages = {469-532},
year = {2016},
isbn = {978-0-12-405935-1},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-405935-1.00010-1},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780124059351000101},
author = {Pijush K. Kundu and Ira M. Cohen and David R. Dowling},
}

@article{Prandtl:1904,
title = {\"{U}ber Fl\"{u}ssikeitsbewegung bei sehr kleiner Reibung},
author = {Prandtl, L},
year = {1904}
}

@article{Prandtl:1918,
title = {Tragflügeltheorie},
author = {Prandtl, L},
year = {1918}
}

@article{JONES:1972,
title = {The prediction of laminarization with a two-equation model of turbulence},
journal = {International Journal of Heat and Mass Transfer},
volume = {15},
number = {2},
pages = {301-314},
year = {1972},
issn = {0017-9310},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/0017-9310(72)90076-2},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0017931072900762},
author = {W.P Jones and B.E Launder},
}

@article{LAUNDER:1974,
title = {The numerical computation of turbulent flows},
journal = {Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering},
volume = {3},
number = {2},
pages = {269-289},
year = {1974},
issn = {0045-7825},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/0045-7825(74)90029-2},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0045782574900292},
author = {B.E. Launder and D.B. Spalding},
}

@article{Wilcox:2008,
title = {Formulation of the $k-\omega$ Turbulence Model Revisited},
journal = {AIAA Journal},
volume = {46},
number = {11},
pages = {2823-2838},
year = {2008},
author = {Wilcox , D.C},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.2514/1.36541}
}

@article{Menter:1992,
title = {Influence of freestream values on $k-\omega$ turbulence model predictions},
journal = {AIAA Journal},
volume = {30},
number = {6},
year = {1992},
author = {Menter, FR},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.2514/3.11115}
}

%WEBPAGES OR SLIDES
@misc{YTFM101a:2021, 
    title = {\emph{The k - epsilon Turbulence Model}},
    publisher = {Fluid Mechanics 101},
    author = {Wimshurst, A.},
    howpublished = {Available at \url{https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnJ8lIgfDbkrNyps1_36tNRRQ7hLzPFhV} \newline Date Accessed: 2021/01/10},
    year = {2019}
}

@misc{CFD:2017,
    title = {\emph{Reynolds stress model (RSM)}},
    publisher = {cfd-online},
    howpublished = {Available at \url{https://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Reynolds_stress_model_(RSM)} Date Accessed: 2021/02/07}
}

@misc{NASA:2020,
    title = {SSG/LRR Full Reynolds Stress Model},
    publisher = {Langley Research Center},
    author = {NASA},
    howpublished = {Available at \url{https://turbmodels.larc.nasa.gov/rsm-ssglrr.html} Date Accessed: 2021/01/11}
}

@misc{Mourada:2020,
    title        = {\emph{Derivation of the Navier-Stokes Equations}},
    author       = {Jousef Mourad},
    publisher    = {Jousef Mourad},
    howpublished = {Avalaible at \url{https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-K7XxqaUNye0co-PFb-YJLfrFpvbYU33} Date Accessed: 2021/04/29}
}
@misc{Mouradb:2020,
    title        = {\emph{Derivation of the Mass Continuity Equation}},
    author       = {Jousef Mourad},
    publisher    = {Jousef Mourad},
    howpublished = {Avalaible at \url{https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-K7XxqaUNye0co-PFb-YJLfrFpvbYU33} Date Accessed: 2021/04/26}
}
@misc{Mouradc:2020,
    title        = {\emph{Derivation of the Energy Equation}},
    author       = {Jousef Mourad},
    publisher    = {Jousef Mourad},
    howpublished = {Avalaible at \url{https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-K7XxqaUNye0co-PFb-YJLfrFpvbYU33} Date Accessed: 2021/05/03}
}


@misc{Comsol:2017,
    title = {\emph{The Boussinesq Approximation}}, 
    publisher = {Comsol inc.},
    author = {Comsol},
    year = {2017},
    howpublished = {Available at \url{https://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/boussinesq-approximation#:~:text=The%20Boussinesq%20approximation%20is%20a,of%20the%20Navier%2DStokes%20equations.&text=It%20assumes%20that%20variations%20in,give%20rise%20to%20buoyancy%20forces.} Date Accessed: 2021/05/12}
}

@misc{StokesB:2021,
title = {Sir George Gabriel Stokes, 1st Baronet.},
author = {Britannica, T. Editors of Encyclopaedia},
publisher = {Encyclopedia Britannica}, 
year = {2021},
howpublished = {Available at \url{https://www.britannica.com/biography/Sir-George-Gabriel-Stokes-1st-Baronet} Date Accessed: 2021/05/01}
}

@misc{ReynoldsB:2021,
title = {Osborne Reynolds},
author = {Britannica, T. Editors of Encyclopaedia.},
publisher = {Encyclopaedia Britannica},
year = {2021},
howpublished = {Availabe at \url{https://www.britannica.com/biography/Osborne-Reynolds} Date Accessed: 2021/05/14}
}

@misc{BruntonY1:2021,
title = {Turbulence: Reynolds Averaged Navier-Stokes (Part 1, Mass Continuity Equation)},
author = {Steve L. Brunton},
year = {2021},
howpublished = {Available at \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDt-HJEXK6g} Date Accessed: 2021/05/15}
}

@misc{BruntonY2:2021,
title = {Turbulence: Reynolds Averaged Navier Stokes (RANS) Equations (Part 2, Momentum Equation)},
author = {Steve L. Brunton},
year = {2021},
howpublished = {Available at \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe6AxHpvBJU} Date Accessed: 2021/05/15}
}

@misc{NASA:2021,
title = {Langley Research Center Turbulence Modeling Resource},
author = {Christopher, Rumsey},
publisher = {NASA},
year = {2021},
howpublished = {Available at \url{https://turbmodels.larc.nasa.gov/} Date Accessed: 2021/05/16}
}

@misc{Prandtl:2021,
title = {Ludwig Prandtl},
author = {Britannica, T. Editors of Encyclopaedia.},
publisher = {Encyclopaedia Britannica},
year = {2021},
howpublished = {Availabe at \url{https://www.britannica.com/biography/Ludwig-Prandtl} Date Accessed: 2021/05/17}
}
```

The problem lies with `Versteeg:2009`, `Navier:1827`, and `Mouradb:2020`. The file still compiles but I want to remove these errors. I have even tried placing curly braces around all entries within the main entry ie.,

```
@misc{
title = {},
year = {}, 
author = {},
and so on
}
```

Here are the other files for an MWE. 
**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[sectionbib, square, numbers, super, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}  
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand\citeAYS[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1})~\cite{#1}}

\begin{document}

\include{Chapter02/Chapter02}

\end{document}
```

and then **Chapter02.tex**

```
\chapter{Experimental setup}

\section{The models in c++}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The models in c++}
Mention source code and maybe give listings of source code of models or mention them in an appendix and reference it here. \citeAYS{Brunton:2012} , \citeAYS{Adrian:2007}, \citeAYS{Versteeg:2009}, \citeAYS{Navier:1827}, \citeAYS{Mouradb:2020}.\\

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{References/References.bib}
```

Comment: you should make a small but complete example, so that we can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please post a full but minimal example that also uses this bib data. Unrelated, yo really should not be adding `\emph` to the bib data.

Comment: @daleif Yes, it was an old bibliography that had `\emph` in it already. Will remove them when I am closer to the end, or when I can resolve these errors. Will upload a MWE soon.

Comment: if you get the error after removing those entries the error is in code you haven't shown (or code genererated from those entries) use the menu option to delete all the cached files but to get an answer here you will probably need to provide an example, or at least show the error.

Comment: Aside: Whatever else you choose to do, please replace all three instances of `author = {Britannica, T. Editors of Encyclopaedia.},` with `author = {{Encyclopedia Britannica}}`. (Yes, those are double curly braces.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Clearing the cached files actually worked. There seems to be no errors from BibTex anymore.

Comment: @Mico I will be sure to add all the necessary identifiers as you mentioned along with the changes recommended.  Thank you for your help. Just one last sub-question, in my main.tex file you see my new \cite command which you helped me with in another thread. Whenever I use it, there is no auto-fill to read entries from the references.tex file. Why is that?

Comment: @JitishMudgal - Autofill capabilities are determined not by LaTeX or BibTeX but by the editor you use, which woould appear to be Overleaf's built-in editor. For Overleaf-specific questions, please contact the Overleaf help desk. I hear their support staff is top-notch.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for that. I will get right on it.

Comment: Since the immediate problem seems to be that an earlier error was still hanging around because it was being held in an undeleted `.aux` file, this may be a candidate for deletion.

Comment: Surely we have a question somewhere that can serve as a canonical "If you have errors that don't go away, they may be in generated files that should be deleted and regenerated."

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I am unable to reproduce the issue(s) you say you're experiencing if I make your code fragment compilable by employing the `article` document class, the `natbib` and `xurl` packages, and the `unsrtnat` bibliography style. The BibteX log file does contain the following warnings, though:

```
Warning--empty author in Holton:2004
Warning--empty journal in Theodorsen:1933
Warning--empty journal in Theodorsen:1935
Warning--empty journal in Prandtl:1904
Warning--empty journal in Prandtl:1918
Warning--empty year in CFD:2017
Warning--empty year in NASA:2020
Warning--empty year in Mourada:2020
Warning--empty year in Mouradb:2020
Warning--empty year in Mouradc:2020
```

I think it would be an excellent idea to fix these issues ASAP. (In the case of the Holton:2004 entry, it may be that you're using an incorrect entry type. I suggest you replace `@incollection` with `@inbook` -- or, alternatively, supply the missing `author` field.)

Comment: In the case of `Holton:2004` the entry was provided by Elsevier in that format, all I removed was the abstract. Changing it to `@inbook` does not really fix that issue.

Comment: @JitishMudgal - You really need to get used to the fact that publishers, including Elsevier, do *not* always provlde correct BibTeX-type information. In fact, quite often their BibTeX information contains egregious errors. By the way, contrary to your claim, changing the entry type to `@inbook` does make the `Warning--empty author in Holton:2004` warning go away.

Comment: Fair enough. As for the '@inbook', that only leaves overleaf acting up I guess? Because when I change the entry type to `@inbook` I still get a BibTex warning stating: "BibTex: no key,author in Holton:2004".

Comment: @JitishMudgal - Overleaf is *not* "acting up", as you choose to put it. The bibliography style that's in use determines which bibliography-related warning messages are issued. It's only quite recently that you've ventured the piece of information that you use the `chicago` bibliography style. When I wrote my answer, this crucial piece of information was not yet available, and I was in no position to anticipate it. And, yes, I'd still strive to eliminate all bib warning messages.